# How to instantiate Http service in main.ts manually

Tags: angular, http

I need to instantiate Http in main.ts manually. I found some answer using HTTP_PROVIDERS like below, but looks like HTTP_PROVIDERS is deprecated. Any idea how can I do this?

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
const http = injector.get(Http);
```

I will then use this http object to call the server and bootstrap the appmodule in the response. Something like the code below:

```
http.get("app/config/config.json").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(resp=>{
      platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

})
```

Comment: Do you mind me asking what are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: I will load a config file and than bootstrap the Appmodule in its response. @IgorSoloydenko

Comment: You can use plain old js XMLHttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest but I don't know whether this would effect the zone or not.

Comment: i tried it, but i get this error `Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 115:35 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Repo/rvm-web-ui/AdaRvmWebClient/src/app/app.module.ts` @echonax

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is to use the Fetch API:

```
fetch('config.json').then(res => res.json()).then((resp) =>{
   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to call controller to get environment info from config file instead of using environment.ts and this is how i did it, i think it could help you

**Main.ts**

```
fetch("/SomeControllerEndpoint").then(function (response) { 
response.json().then(function (response) {    
if (response.status === "success" && response.result.toLowerCase().indexOf('prod') !== -1) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(() => InitializeApp())
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

So this way, custom code is applied before application is bootstrapped.