# Angular6 Using fetched config variable in module forRoot()

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my app I need to use `ng-intercom` https://github.com/CaliStyle/ng-intercom, which requires a config key to be set in `forRoot()` method.

The config key is loaded from an API call, done in `main.ts`. The config is fetched from API, then set to `APP_CONFIG` in `AppConfigService` and then the app is bootstrapped.

**main.ts**

```
const appConfigRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
appConfigRequest.addEventListener('load', onAppConfigLoad);
appConfigRequest.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/lf0ns');
appConfigRequest.send();

// Callback executed when app config JSON file has been loaded.
function onAppConfigLoad() {
    const config = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    initConfig(config);
}

// Sets fetched config to AppConfigService constant APP_CONFIG and calls bootstrap()
function initConfig(config) {
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([AppConfigService]);
    const configService = injector.get(AppConfigService);
    configService.set(config);

    bootstrap();
}

function bootstrap() {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then().catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

**app-config.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export let APP_CONFIG: any = {};

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {

    constructor() {}

    public set(config) {
        APP_CONFIG = Object.assign(config);
    }
}
```

In `AppModule` I import the `APP_CONFIG` and use the key from the config in the `forRoot()` of the `IntercomModule`:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, InjectionToken, Inject, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { APP_CONFIG } from './../shared/services/app-config.service';
import { IntercomModule } from 'ng-intercom';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule,
    IntercomModule.forRoot({
        appId : APP_CONFIG.intercomKey,
        updateOnRouterChange: false
    })
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**Config example:**

```
{
  "production": true,
  "envName": "staging",
  "apiBaseURL": "//api.staging.site.com/v1/",
  "intercomKey": "qz0b98qo"
}
```

The problem: when the IntercomModule is initialized, the config key is undefined `APP_CONFIG.intercomKey`, because the config has not been fetched from API yet.

How do I make sure the config is available when the modules are initialized? Any ideas?

I have tried calling a function in the `forRoot()` method before but got an error `Function calls are not supported in decorators` when compiling the app with AOT

See also stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-intercom-issue

Comment: You could try using `async/await`. [Here](https://javascript.info/async-await) is a good exemple how to use it. This should do the trick. Also consider using Angular's `HttpClient` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. The `HttpClient` will wrap your request into promises what make it easy to work with `async/await`. You can see a guide [here](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Comment: Thanks, will try that out. I was using `XMLHttpRequest` for IE11 support.

Comment: And it seems HttpClient can not be used in main.ts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681396/how-to-instantiate-http-service-in-main-ts-manually

Comment: So since you will have to use `XMLHttpRequest` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969495/in-javascript-how-do-i-should-i-use-async-await-with-xmlhttprequest) is a good exemple on how to work with `async/await` and it.

Comment: Using promises does not seem to resolve my problem. Angular seems to create  the AppModule (line 10) before hitting the code that does the request (line 36). See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-intercom-issue-c4gc8h?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: You forgot to use `async/await`. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-intercom-issue-mmcjsj

Comment: I think I see what is going on here. Seens like `AppModule` is loaded before `main.ts` execute it's functions.

Comment: Exactly. Do you have any idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code in app.module.ts is executed as soon as you import it in your main.ts. You have to dynamically import it to achieve your goal. I updated your [example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-intercom-issue-shhf69?file=src%2Fmain.ts) to show a solution.

You might have to check out how TypeScript is transpiling dynamic imports, though. I'm not sure, if it is currently possible to target an ES version that is widely supported. See also the TypeScript docs on the topic [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios).

If it is possible to request and cache the app-config(s) on the server, that would be a cleaner solution, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I had to update my `tsconfig.json` with `"module": "esNext"` and `"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule" : "./app/app.module#AppModule"
  }` to avoid errors when compiling. It works now when serving in dev mode but when I compile for prod with AOT I get following error: "Unhandled Promise rejection: No NgModule metadata found for 'e'"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and @realhans' answer also broke AOT for me.

The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54478230/4337765) solves the issue while AOT keeps working.