# Angular load external configuration before AppModule loads

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the following scenario (Angular v7):

1. Load configuration parameters (API server URL and Auth server URL) from an external endpoint (JSON), **before** the AppModule is loaded
2. Pass configuration to AppModule (OAuth2 module)
3. Compile the app with AOT

Point 2 is key here, and looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    OAuthModule.forRoot({
      resourceServer: {
        allowedUrls: [API_SERVER_URL], // <== we need to set the value that we loaded from the external endpoint (JSON) here
        sendAccessToken: true
      }
    }),
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What I've tried to far:

- A solution with [APP_INITIALIZER](https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e?gi=4ee3389eaa27). This doesn't work, as the `OAuthModule.forRoot()` is triggered before the `APP_INITIALIZER` can download the external configuration JSON.
- Load the config [with an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111073/4337765) in the `main.ts` into the Angular environment variables, then bootstrap the AppModule. Also doesn't work due to the `import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';` statement in `main.ts`, which causes the AppModule to load and fire `OAuthModule.forRoot()` before the external config is loaded ([this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561650/4337765) confirms this behavior).
- [Load the AppModule dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561650/4337765) in `main.ts`, so without the `import` statement on top. [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-intercom-issue-shhf69?file=src%2Fmain.ts) is the StackBlitz example given in that comment. **It works**, but 1) breaks lazy loading `WARNING in Lazy routes discovery is not enabled.` and 2) doesn't work with AOT compiling. It **does** come very close to what I need.

Curious to hear if someone is aware of another method to get external configuration loaded **before** the AppModule loads.

StackBlitz for option 3 (Load the AppModule dynamically): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8hdty

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Angular documentation has a great chapter called NgModule FAQs which contains the following section:

> **What if two modules provide the same service?**
>
> ...
>
> If NgModule A provides a service for token 'X' and imports an
>   NgModule B that also provides a service for token 'X', then NgModule
>   A's service definition "wins".

In other words, you can override OAuthModuleConfig for your library in AppModule:

**main.ts**

```
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/lf0ns');
  const config = await response.json();

  environment['allowedUrls'] = config.apiBaseURL;

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
})();
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OAuthModule, OAuthModuleConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: OAuthModuleConfig,
      useFactory: () => ({
        resourceServer: {
          allowedUrls: [environment['allowedUrls']],
          sendAccessToken: true
        }
      })
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Note that we should also use `useFactory` instead of `useValue` so we  don't depend on when `AppModule` is imported.

Comment: You're a hero! Thanks for the clear explanation. This does the trick, and I just had to make a minor change to get AOT working. Will post that in a separate answer.

Comment: I need to do the same thing you guys did so I'm following this post but I'm getting an error in my app.main.ts "cannot find name environment."

Answer (score 6):

Another option here. @yurzui answer works, but it requires   the use of `useFactory` which make the code harder to understand.

`useFactory` is required because Angular `@NgModule` decorators will be executed as soon as the `AppModule` is imported in `main.ts` and so the configuration isn't loaded yet.

So I decided to load the configuration even before that by adding a script in the scripts section of `angular.js`. Here's how:

**src/config/load.js:**

```
// This file is added to the scripts section of 'angular.json' so it can run before Angular bootstrap process.
// It responsability is to load app configuration from JSON files.
(() => {
  const fetchSync = url => {
    // The code below will log the following warning: "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.",
    // but since we want the configuration to be set before Angular bootstrap process, we ignore this warning.
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, false);
    xhr.send(null);
    return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  };

  // We attach the fetched configuration to the 'window' global variable to access it later from Angular.
  window.configuration = {
    ...fetchSync('config/config.base.json'),
    ...fetchSync('config/config.local.json'),
  };
})();
```

**angular.json:**

```
  // ...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        // ...
        "assets": [
          // ...
          "src/config/config.base.json",
          "src/config/config.local.json"
        ],
        "scripts": ["src/config/load.js"],
  // ...
```

**src/config/configuration.ts:**

```
import get from 'lodash/get';

export class Configuration {
  // We get the configuration from the 'window.configuration' property which as been set earlier by 'config/load.js'.
  private static value = (window as any).configuration;

  /**
   * Get configuration value.
   * @param path The path of the configuration value. Use '.' for nested values.
   * @param defaultValue The returned value if the given path doesn't exist.
   * @example
   * const baseUrl = Configuration.get<string>('apis.github.baseUrl');
   */
  static get<T>(path: string, defaultValue?: T): T {
    return get(Configuration.value, path, defaultValue);
  }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
OAuthModule.forRoot({
  resourceServer: {
    allowedUrls: Configuration.get('allowedUrls')
    sendAccessToken: true
  }
}),
```

See [this](https://dev.to/johnphamous/how-to-make-your-bundle-size-smaller-if-you-re-using-lodash-with-angular-55lh) if you have problem with lodash.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @yurzui's answer, if you try this in AOT (e.g. `ng build --prod`), you will get

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
>     Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'AuthModule'
>       'AuthModule' contains the error at src\app\core\auth.module.ts(29,23)
>         Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.

so we create an exported function for the factory:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OAuthModule, OAuthModuleConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export function oAuthConfigFactory() : OAuthModuleConfig {
  return {
    resourceServer: {
      allowedUrls: [environment.servers.apiServer],
      sendAccessToken: true
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: OAuthModuleConfig,
      useFactory: oAuthConfigFactory
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: How do you load the same for imports section in app.module.ts, it is giving me an error while calling the export function inside import  and .forRoot. I need to assign something like a string inside a foorRoot of NgOidcClientModule where the expected parameter is a string. I can return objects easily using the export function but for string and primitive types, it is not getting called. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I am suggesting you this simple solution as I have implemented this few months ago in my project.

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ...
        OAuthModule.forRoot({
          resourceServer: {
            allowedUrls: GetApiUrl(), // <== we need to set the value that we loaded from the external endpoint (JSON) here
            sendAccessToken: true
          }
        }),
        ...
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
    
    export function GetApiUrl() {
      const jsonFile = `assets/config.dev.json`; //path to config file
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', jsonFile, false);  // get app settings
      request.send(null);
      const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      return response.ApiUrl;
  }
```

1. Step 1, Create function as I did with the name GetApiUrl().
2. Get Json file synchronously using XMLHttpRequest.
3. Return api url from the response object.
4. Call the GetApiUrl() function where you want to put api url.

Note: For external json file, put the complete url to the file. In my example json file exist in my own project so I just put its path to the file.