# Azure AD MSAL app.module.ts dynmic config loading on different environment

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

I am using MSAL which is a microsoft authentication library for my angular project. In my `app.module.ts`, I added the msalModule in the import section as follows:

This is fine while coding and figuring how to get it work during development, but I need to dynamically set variables like `redirectUri`, `postLogoutRediectUri`, and the `clientID` to different values for the production environment. I tried using an object like:

`Object.getClientID()`, `Object.getRedirectUri()`, but I get an error that functions are not allowed in decorator.

Is there a way to set the static variable before the `app.module.ts` is called? Or is there another way to dynamically load the correct environment variables for MSAL?

Thanks

```
salModule.forRoot({

  clientID: "<my-client-id>",

  authority: "https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signin",

  redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/dashboard",

  /* default is true */
  validateAuthority: false, 


  cacheLocation : "localStorage", 

  postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/", 


  popUp: false,            
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're facing is related to asynchronous providers https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279

I was having the same problem with MSAL and my workaround is to disable aot and use global scope, it's not an elegant solution but it works (I hope I remember all the steps):

1. inside the head section of you HTML page load a custom js with `<script src="assets/conf/config.js"></script>`, the content of that file should be something like this: `window.MY_CONF = { MY_VAR:'my var value here' };`
2. set aot to false in your configurations in the `angular.json` file
3. in your angular module import MSAL with `MsalModule.forRoot(window['MY_CONF'].MY_VAR)`

Now you can replace `config.js` before launching the build task and get an environment-dependant MSAL configuration.

Note: this post [Angular load external configuration before AppModule loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469571/angular-load-external-configuration-before-appmodule-loads/54478230) uses the `useFactory` feature to achieve the same result in the angular-way, but AFAIK Msal lib does not support that. There's a specific github issue here, you might want to chek it out: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/481