# Set Angular environment from main.ts

Tags: angular, config, environment

I want to load some configuration for OAuth before the application loads. I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469571/angular-load-external-configuration-before-appmodule-loads) post but I'm getting an error in my app.main.ts when i try to set the environment variables:

```
cannot find name environment
```

Here is my app.main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ProdConfig } from './blocks/config/prod.config';
import { HelloworldAppModule } from './app.module';

ProdConfig();

if (module['hot']) {
  module['hot'].accept();
}

(async () => {
    const response = await fetch ("../../../../../config.json")
    const config = await response.json();
    environment['issuer'] = config.issuer;
    environment['redirectUri'] = config.redirectUri;
    environment['clientId'] = config.clientId;

    platformBrowserDynamic()
        .bootstrapModule(HelloworldAppModule, { preserveWhitespaces: true })
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        .then(() => console.log('Application started'))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
})();
```

How do I set the environment from app.main.ts?

Comment: You should import `environment` from `environment.ts` file

Comment: will that make it so that when I import the environment elsewhere, it has the values that I set from main.ts?

Comment: Yes, since you're mutating this object it will be visible everywhere

Comment: awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use environment variables, you need to [import](https://angular.io/guide/build)

```
import Environment from "./Environment.ts"
```